# How to retrieve text value of an element for selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to retreive text value of an element  for my selenium test but getText() function does return NULL for that element.

```
String ProjectName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='ProjectLabelComponent']")).getText()
```

I would be grateful for any advice. Thanks[image]

Comment: Could you post the code you're using?

Comment: Could you confirm if the locator you have used doesn't have duplicate elements? If no, could you try 
String innerText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return
arguments[0].innerText", element); OR
String innerText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return
arguments[0].textContent", element);